# HTTPS only for certain folder

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have HTTPS certificate and I wont to limit it to only one folder /xcart/ but I dont want to be to accessible from other folder and pages. Is it possible to make this limitation using .htaccess ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/xcart/.*
 RewriteRule  (.*)  http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [R,L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/xcart/.*
 RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1    [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, working just OK, however my COMODO SSL certification shows a warning that page include other resources which are not secure. Do you maybe know why is this happening once I apply this inside htacccess?

Comment: When you use an SSL connection for transferring web pages but other resources like CSS, images, scripts are linked by **HTTP**, browsers show that message. You should use relative paths or code a little to change **http** to **https**  when web page is using **https**.